# Escaping $_ in powershell inside python

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, escaping, quotes

Can you please tell me why the dollar sign output does not work?
I used this construction:

```
commands = (
    f'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "&Get-ADUser -Filter (\\"OfficePhone -like {internal_number}\\") '
    f'-Properties SID | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString '
    f'-AsPlainText \\"{gen_password}\\" -Force -Verbose) -PAssThru | Unlock-ADAccount"'
)
```

Now I am trying to change my query in powershell like this

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties OfficePhone, Mobile, SID | Where-Object {  $_.OfficePhone -eq "888888" -or   $_.Mobile -eq "888888"  } | Select-Object SID
```

But when I write it in python with (**`**) dollar escape

```
f'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "&Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties OfficePhone, Mobile, SID | Where-Object "{`$_.OfficePhone -eq {internal_number} -or `$_.Mobile -eq {internal_number}}" '
```

an error occurs

```
(`$_.OfficePhone -eq {internal_number} -or `$_.Mobile -eq {internal_number})
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the embedded `"..."` around the `Where-Object` argument (it expects just a script block, not a string; in cases where you truly need embedded `"` chars., escape them as `\"` for PowerShell, which in an f-string means `\\"`)
- No need to escape `$` characters.
- In order to embed *verbatim* `{` and `}` characters in a Python [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals), escape them as `{{` and `}}`, respectively.

Therefore:

```py
f'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties OfficePhone, Mobile, SID | Where-Object {{ $_.OfficePhone -eq {internal_number} -or $_.Mobile -eq {internal_number} }}"'
```